# Pass in custom query variables to a GraphQL query in an Insomnia Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, graphql, insomnia

Using an [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest) *design document*, I created a *query* and a *unit test* that runs tests on that query. The query has a *query variable* which is configured as part of the query in the "Debug" tab in Insomnia.

The query looks like this:

```
query Test($bar: String!) {
  dummy(where: {foo: {contains: $bar}} ) { foo }
}
```

With the following query variables:

```
{
  "bar": "Bar"
}
```

On the "Tests" tab I can create a unit test and select the "Test" query. Is it possible to pass in different query variables as the one configured in the "Debug" tab?

I want to create two unit tests, one that uses the query variable defined in the "Debug" tab and one that uses a different query variable, e.g.:

```
{
  "bar": "capybara"
}
```

My current solution is to duplicate the query in the "Debug" tab for each unit test. While this works, it obviously creates a lot of duplication which makes adapting the tests to changes in the GraphQL schema a lot more labor intense than it could be.

Answer (score 0):

One of the good things about a variable is that you can vary them!

simply update the variable to the value you want. If you are worried about losing the value then you can do something like this:

```
{
    "bar": "Bar",
    "bar1": "capybara",
}
```

Just update the variable name as necessary; you would need to change the name of the variable you wanted to use to bar and all other variables to another name - bar followed by a number is simple to change back.

```
{
    "bar1": "Bar",
    "bar": "capybara",
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution. I want to be able to pass in different query variables for the same query. The goal is to have multiple tests that use the same query but with different query variables. I updated the question to make it more clear.